# File or directory not found in IIS7 in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have published my project in IIS7. When I browse particular .ashx file in the browser, I got File or directory not found issue.

[image]

When I browse the same .ashx file in my local server file details have been shown. But in my local PC file details have not been shown. How to resolve that isse?

Comment: check if .ashx is an allowed extension or not in the MIME types.

Comment: @din, Other than one particular .ashx file remaining .ashx files are found.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you few steps:

1. Make sure you have added the file into your .Net project. The file is probably missing in your project.
2. Also double check the spelling. Sometimes is just a typo.
3. Type the path manually in your browser and see where it is looking for the file.

These options might be enough.

Comment: I have checked in my local server. File has been found. I got above mentioned issue only in my local PC.